# Nodejs : Increment sequence number inside foreach loop sequentially

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async.js

I have been working on MEAN stack project that has no use of Angular for now. I am stuck at a point where I tried so many things to get rid of but no options worked. I have been using even emitter to handle asynchronous nature of Node.js to execute logical validations sequentially. My code is

```
            flowController.on('12', function (combinedArray, finalPickSubListInsertArray) {

            var dummyObject = [];

            async.forEach(finalPickSubListInsertArray, function (element, callback) {

                locationStoreModel.findOne({'_id': element.locationStoreId, 'activeStatus': 1}, function (err, locationRow) {

                    if (err) {

                        flowController.emit('ERROR', {message: "Location data missing! Records tampered/removed from system", status: 'error', statusCode: '404'});
                    } else {

                        pickSubListModel.find({'pickListId': pickListId, 'activeStatus': 1}).sort({'sequence': -1}).exec(function (err, pickSubListRow) {

                            if (err) {

                                res.json({message: 'Internal Error fetching pick sublists!', status: 'error', statusCode: '500'});
                            } else {

                                var sequence = (pickSubListRow.length == 0) ? 1 : (pickSubListRow[0].sequence + (dummyObject.length + 1));

                                var newPickSubList = new pickSubListModel();

                                newPickSubList.pickListId = pickListId;
                                newPickSubList.itemCode = itemCode;
                                newPickSubList.itemStoreId = element.itemStore;
                                newPickSubList.itemDescription = itemDescription;
                                newPickSubList.requiredQuantity = requiredQuantity;

                                newPickSubList.sequence = sequence;
                                newPickSubList.createdBy = createdBy;
                                newPickSubList.timeCreated = timeInInteger;

                                newPickSubList.save(function (err, insertedRecordDetails) {
                                    if (err) {

                                        res.json({message: 'INTERNAL SERVER ERROR, UNKNOWN SERVER ERROR HAS OCCURRED', status: 'error', statusCode: '500'});
                                    } else {

                                        pickListModel.update(
                                                {'_id': pickListId},
                                                {'$addToSet': {'pickSubLists': insertedRecordDetails._id.toString()}},
                                                function (err) {

                                                    if (err) {
                                                        // error while adding records
                                                        res.json({message: "Unable to make update! Try again after some time.", status: 'error', statusCode: '500'});
                                                    } else {

                                                        dummyObject.push({process: 'done'});

                                                        callback();
                                                    }
                                                });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }, function (err) {

                if (err) {

                    res.json({message: 'Unable to create pick-sublist! Try again later.', status: 'error', statusCode: '304'});
                } else {

                    res.json({message: 'New Pick-Sublist added into the system!', status: 'success', statusCode: '200'});
                }
            });
        });
```

Here I am trying to insert serially records into my MongoDB collection and each record that is inserted will get an incrementing sequence number. **My problem is when I enter into foreach then the records get inserted into collection but all records gets the same sequence number which I want to be in an incremental manner.**

I did a series of 11 validations followed by which it reached to event emitter 12 and now it's time to insert records into the database. My situation is like I ate the whole elephant and just the tail remained & that tail is getting hard for me to digest...

Any suggestions on how to cater it would be really appreciated...

Comment: Did you try `async.eachSeries` to make it sync nature?

Comment: no dear...ok let me see it

Comment: Yup its amazing! It worked like a charm...thanks